# PID control loop exit condition

Tags: microcontroller, pid-controller

I'm helping programming a FLL LEGO robot (two motorized wheels and a ballpoint in the back are the contacts with the ground), experimenting with a PID control to make it turn. It may seem overkill, but everything else, including a pure proportional control can't account well for the "not so precise" motors and sensors.

That said, **what is a good exiting condition for a PID algorithm?** 
Of course just waiting some time until the oscillation becomes imperceptible is good, but I wonder what the literature has to say, since in my application I need control back to the main program asap to do other things.

My guesses:

- fine tune the number of iterations with the derivative and proportional therms arbitrarily close to the setpoint
- a parallel control loop that "pulls the brake" after the setpoint has been reached a certain number of times (and fine tune it too)

If this is not the right place to ask this question feel free to move it wherever you want.

Comment: Why would you exit PID? In my world it always works. Any higher level algorithm may be built above it.

Comment: You mean to actually keep it working behind, in parallel to everything else the robot is doing? I didn't think about it.

Maybe, but our interaction with the motors is pretty high level, so that would mean that, for any other movement the output of this control should be added to every other output needed which adds a lot of complexity but should definitely work.

Comment: Not in parallel. Higher level algorithm produces a command, which is the PID input. PID output is probably voltage or something

Comment: Do you know how a PID is usually implemented in real time systems?

Comment: Not really, I'm still reading on the internet, looking at some example codes. I believe I understood the idea and the code, but I just can't get away with how it can be both high level and not running in paralell (with the final output being a combination of the PID output and the other programs running).

A lower-level PID with higher-level commands seems ok to me, but not any high-high combo.

Comment: Ok, it's a long talk, but for the starters, you should enter the PID routine once per given time, like once per 1msec. It should be very precise, so you should use timer and interrupt. In fact, all higher level activity may naturally go to background or to be in the same interrupt.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I'll delete this post since it seems my question is more from the fact that I still can't grasp the concept fully

Comment: Why?! Keep it. When you will make up your mind, post an update.

Comment: I think you might not grasp the integral part. This is the sum of all errors over time, which is continuously updated, to have the regulator compensate for errors and lower the oscillation caused by the proportional. For this to work, the regulator has to update on regular basis - it should never "exit". The longer it runs, the better the "I part" becomes. And suppose the regulator error nature changes after running for a while - you'll want the PID to compensate.

Answer (score 1):

A PID algorithm corrects a control signal based on an error, and its goal is to reduce the error to zero.

By 'turning' I understand that you want your robot to move to a required position or to a certain distance. In that case, the error is the distance that the robot has yet to cover, and the control signal could be the PWM duty cycle that power the motorized wheels.

Consider this pseudo-code:

```
requiredPosition = obtainRequiredPosition();
error = requiredPosition - currentPosition;
while(error <> 0) {
    correction = PID(error);
    averagePower += correction;
    applyPower(averagePower);

    // Wait a little: either with a waiting loop
    // or, better, implement the whole thing in iterrupts.
    wait();

    currentPosition = captureCurrentPosition();
    error = requiredPosition - position;
};
```

I don't think you need the integral part of the PID. You don't need your robot to spend an equal amount of time with positive and negative error.

As an example, you would need the integral part to control the helm of a boat: When the boat is heading in a specific direction, you want to compensate the time going too much to the left with an equal time going too much to the right.

Comment: During my robotic course at the university me and my classmates made small cars that used PID regulators to keep the cars in the center of a labyrinth. The **integral part was not necessary** since there was no constant error pushing the car around in a particular direction. If the labyrinth would have been tilted, say 30 degrees, then the integral part would've been needed. - So you're right.